# Angular Bootstrap Directive Typeahead validation not working... Can't get updated model info

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-bootstrap

I have the following in Angular BootStrap directives: Editable is set to false, but I can't figure out how to get the $invalid value. It always shows as valid. I am using Angular-bootstrap .11 with Angular 1.3... It seems as if the model never gets updated so that $invalid becomes true...

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error':myForm.accountName.$invalid &&  myForm.accountName.$dirty }">

    <form name="myForm">
    ...

       <label>Seller: {{currentLot.sellerCode}}</label> 

        <input type="text"  name="accountName" placeholder="" class="form-control" ng-model="currentLot.accountName"   
                            typeahead="item.sellerCode + ' ' + item.name  for item in searchGeneric('accounts',$viewValue)" 
                            typeahead-loading="loadingAccountsSellerCode" typeahead-on-select="accountSelected($item)"
                            typeahead-wait-ms="2" typeahead-min-length="2"  typeahead-editable="false" 
                            typeahead-append-to-body="false" >

                             <div class="warning" ng-show="!myForm.accountName.$invalid &&  lotForm.myForm.$dirty">
                                   <i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> Values must exist in the list...
                             </div>

                             <i ng-show="loadingAccountsSellerCode" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i> 

...
```

Comment: !myForm.accountName.$invalid?

Comment: Demo of the problem in Plunker... https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2308

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original code the form isn't the first element in my angular template. I moved the form declaration and it works. A bug perhaps in Angular or the directives.